# Ionic Aangular :No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to build an Ionic Android app but no matter what i do i get this error, here is the full error

===========================================================================

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251 (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251 (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :appProject evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Peter Snee\Documents\AngularIonic\quotesApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
C:\Users\Peter Snee\Documents\AngularIonic\quotesApp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Peter Snee\Documents\AngularIonic\quotesApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

===========================================================================

I have uninstalled Android studio, i have changed a few environment variables, nothing seems to be working for me so im probably missing something,

Any help is greatly appreciated !

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it, 
It turns out my paths were wrong in the environment variables, 
I ran 
android list sdk

in the cmd and got the exact paths,

rookie mistake but sure look.